# How to play youtube in highest quality in a wpf application

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I have a request from a client who want to be able to play a video from youtube in the best available quality possible. Right now im using the webbrowser component in my wpf application and pointing it to the .swf file, but it seems that it plays the lowest quality available and not the higest quality available. Any ideas on how to accomplish this.

Further more the client would like to play an entire playlist so the quality might change from video to video as to which is the highest quality.

Anyone got a solution for this? Or is it that a simple link to a youtube video is not enough and i need to go through the youtube API?

cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on Youtube API page at section `Data API` http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api

To query all avaliable video quality check this http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_quality

Comment: Thank you for the links. But the first link is to extract data, which i did. The next link is to a flash player documentation... i cant see how i can do this in WPF?

Comment: @H4mm3rHead: I dont know if this can be done in "pure" WPF but I suppose that you will do it in web brwser control. You can interact with it and call javascript methods from C# side as described here - http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/